# JFace libraries stand-alone download (not picked from Eclipse plug-ins)

Tags: jface

I would like to use all of the JFace functionality but include in my project only the very minimum in terms of external `jar`s.

Is it possible to download the typical `.jar`s required to build an SWT/JFace app without having to download Eclipse first and then to pick the right files out of the `plugins` directory?

e.g. these files..

- org.eclipse.core.commands_.jar
- org.eclipse.equinox.common_.jar
- org.eclipse.jface_.jar
- org.eclipse.osgi_.jar
- org.eclipse.ui.workbench_.jar
- ...

Is it even possible to map classes to `jar` files and download links for said files?

Note: I am looking for the "official library files download page" (a little bit like this page for SWT: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.1-201209141800/#SWT), not a "look-up service" like: http://www.jarfinder.com

Here is what I picked out of my `eclipse-SDK-4.2.2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64` folder, but it felt like **trial and error**:

- org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.2.v20130123-162658.jar
- org.eclipse.core.commands.source_3.6.2.v20130123-162658.jar
- org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841.jar
- org.eclipse.equinox.common.source_3.6.100.v20120522-1841.jar
- org.eclipse.jface_3.8.102.v20130123-162658.jar
- org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.6.0.v20120912-132807.jar
- org.eclipse.jface.databinding.source_1.6.0.v20120912-132807.jar
- org.eclipse.jface.source_3.8.102.v20130123-162658.jar
- org.eclipse.jface.text_3.8.2.v20121126-164145.jar
- org.eclipse.jface.text.source_3.8.2.v20121126-164145.jar
- org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar
- org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20120522-1822.jar
- org.eclipse.osgi.services.source_3.3.100.v20120522-1822.jar
- org.eclipse.osgi.source_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar
- org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.2.300.v20120913-144807.jar
- org.eclipse.osgi.util.source_3.2.300.v20120913-144807.jar
- org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.104.0.v20130204-164612.jar
- org.eclipse.ui.workbench.source_3.104.0.v20130204-164612.jar
- org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_3.8.0.v20120523-1310.jar
- org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.source_3.8.0.v20120523-1310.jar

Comment: Here's the SWT download page.  http://www.eclipse.org/swt/  You'll need to download the SWT files for your specific environment (Windows, Linux).

Comment: I am asking specifically for JFace and not SWT?

Comment: SWT includes JFace.  JFace components are built from SWT.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc SWT do not include JFace. JFace extends SWT and is dependent on SWT.

Answer (score 0):

You can either choose Eclipse RCP SDK, or go for the whole Eclipse SDK (JFace Text, for example, is only available in the latter). You'll have to dig up the desired jars and sources from the plugins directory.

JFace is available in those distributions. For some unfathomable reason, it is not available as a stand-alone download.